# ImageView Based on SharedPreference

Tags: android, imageview, sharedpreferences

I have searched all over and tried to follow examples but I am unable to implement SharedPreferences.

I am creating a VERY low tech PunchCard.  NFCTag has a text field that says "coffee" I have another that says "sandwich"  I then have 2 Strings with the same name.  Tap the Coffee Tag, it changes the coffee image, Tap the Sandwich tag, it changes that sandwich image.

My question now is... I am able to get it to save the Preference but it is not updating the image, any suggestions would be appreciated..

https://github.com/soboapps/PunchCard - This may give you an idea of what I am trying to do.

Here is my code (I know it's a mess)

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity implements NavigationView.OnNavigationItemSelectedListener {

    public boolean cflag = false;
    public boolean sflag = false;

    private static final String NAV_ITEM_ID = "navItemId" ;
    private static final long DRAWER_CLOSE_DELAY_MS = 300 ;
    private DrawerLayout mDrawerLayout;

    private int mNavItemId;
    private ActionBarDrawerToggle mDrawerToggle;

    private final CoffeeFragment mCoffeeFragment= new CoffeeFragment();
    private final SandwichFragment mSandwichFragment = new SandwichFragment();
    private final AboutFragment mAboutFragment = new AboutFragment();
    private final Handler mDrawerActionHandler = new Handler();

    private static final DateFormat TIME_FORMAT = SimpleDateFormat.getDateTimeInstance();
    private LinearLayout mTagContent;
    private LinearLayout mCoffee1_3Content;

    private NfcAdapter mAdapter;
    private PendingIntent mPendingIntent;
    private NdefMessage mNdefPushMessage;

    private AlertDialog mDialog;

    public static String myTagId;
    public static String myCTagUrl;
    public static String mySTagId;
    public static String mySTagUrl;
    public static String sPayload;

    private ImageView mCoffee1ImageView;
    private ImageView mCoffee2ImageView;
    private ImageView mCoffee3ImageView;
    private ImageView mCoffee4ImageView;
    private ImageView mCoffee5ImageView;
    private ImageView mCoffee6ImageView;
    private ImageView mCoffee7ImageView;
    private ImageView mCoffee8ImageView;
    private ImageView mCoffee9ImageView;

    private ImageView mSandwich1ImageView;
    private ImageView mSandwich2ImageView;
    private ImageView mSandwich3ImageView;
    private ImageView mSandwich4ImageView;
    private ImageView mSandwich5ImageView;
    private ImageView mSandwich6ImageView;
    private ImageView mSandwich7ImageView;
    private ImageView mSandwich8ImageView;
    private ImageView mSandwich9ImageView;

    public SharedPreferences prefs;



    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        prefs = PreferenceManager.getDefaultSharedPreferences(this);

        cflag = prefs.getBoolean("selected", false);

        LayoutInflater inflater = LayoutInflater.from(this);
        LinearLayout content = mCoffee1_3Content;
        View view =  inflater.inflate(R.layout.coffee_fragment, content, false);

        mCoffee1ImageView = (ImageView) view.findViewById(R.id.img_cof_1);

        checkFlag();

        // Initialize Drawer layout -> activity_main
        mDrawerLayout = (DrawerLayout) findViewById(R.id.drawer_layout);

        //Initialize Toolbar android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar
        Toolbar mToolbar = (Toolbar) findViewById(R.id.toolbar);
        setSupportActionBar(mToolbar);

        //Load saved navigation state if present
        if (null==savedInstanceState){
            mNavItemId = R.id.drawer_item_1;
        }else{
            mNavItemId = savedInstanceState.getInt(NAV_ITEM_ID);
        }

        // Listen to navigation events
        NavigationView navigationView = (NavigationView) findViewById(R.id.navigation);
        navigationView.setNavigationItemSelectedListener(this);

        //Select the Correct nav menu item
        navigationView.getMenu().findItem(mNavItemId).setChecked(true);

        // Setup the humberger icon to open and close drawer
        mDrawerToggle = new ActionBarDrawerToggle(this, mDrawerLayout, mToolbar, R.string.open, R.string.close);
        mDrawerLayout.setDrawerListener(mDrawerToggle);
        mDrawerToggle.syncState();

        // navigate function to swich between items id
        // parameter item id
        navigate(mNavItemId);

        mTagContent = (LinearLayout) findViewById(R.id.list);
        mCoffee1_3Content = (LinearLayout) findViewById(R.id.cof_1_3);
        resolveIntent(getIntent());

        mDialog = new AlertDialog.Builder(this).setNeutralButton("Ok", null).create();

        mAdapter = NfcAdapter.getDefaultAdapter(this);
        if (mAdapter == null) {
            showMessage(R.string.error, R.string.no_nfc);
            finish();
            return;
        }

        mPendingIntent = PendingIntent.getActivity(this, 0,
                new Intent(this, getClass()).addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_SINGLE_TOP), 0);
        mNdefPushMessage = new NdefMessage(new NdefRecord[] { newTextRecord(
                "Message from NFC Reader :-)", Locale.ENGLISH, true) });

    }


    public void checkFlag(){

        if(cflag) {

            mCoffee1ImageView.setImageResource(R.drawable.sbp_coffee_free);
        } else {

            mCoffee1ImageView.setImageResource(R.drawable.sbp_coffee);
        }
    }



    private void navigate(final int itemId) {

        switch (itemId){
            case R.id.drawer_item_1:
                //start about fragment
                getFragmentManager().beginTransaction().replace(R.id.content,mCoffeeFragment).commit();
                break;
            case R.id.drawer_item_about:
                //start project fragment
                getFragmentManager().beginTransaction().replace(R.id.content, mAboutFragment).commit();
                break;
        }

    }


    private void showMessage(int title, int message) {
        mDialog.setTitle(title);
        mDialog.setMessage(getText(message));
        mDialog.show();
    }

    private NdefRecord newTextRecord(String text, Locale locale, boolean encodeInUtf8) {
        byte[] langBytes = locale.getLanguage().getBytes(Charset.forName("US-ASCII"));

        Charset utfEncoding = encodeInUtf8 ? Charset.forName("UTF-8") : Charset.forName("UTF-16");
        byte[] textBytes = text.getBytes(utfEncoding);

        int utfBit = encodeInUtf8 ? 0 : (1 << 7);
        char status = (char) (utfBit + langBytes.length);

        byte[] data = new byte[1 + langBytes.length + textBytes.length];
        data[0] = (byte) status;
        System.arraycopy(langBytes, 0, data, 1, langBytes.length);
        System.arraycopy(textBytes, 0, data, 1 + langBytes.length, textBytes.length);

        return new NdefRecord(NdefRecord.TNF_WELL_KNOWN, NdefRecord.RTD_TEXT, new byte[0], data);
    }

    @Override
    protected void onResume() {

        super.onResume();
        checkFlag();
        if (mAdapter != null) {
            if (!mAdapter.isEnabled()) {
                showWirelessSettingsDialog();
            }
            mAdapter.enableForegroundDispatch(this, mPendingIntent, null, null);
            mAdapter.enableForegroundNdefPush(this, mNdefPushMessage);
        }
    }

    @Override
    protected void onPause() {
        super.onPause();
        if (mAdapter != null) {
            mAdapter.disableForegroundDispatch(this);
            mAdapter.disableForegroundNdefPush(this);
        }
    }

    private void showWirelessSettingsDialog() {
        AlertDialog.Builder builder = new AlertDialog.Builder(this);
        builder.setMessage(R.string.nfc_disabled);
        builder.setPositiveButton(android.R.string.ok, new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
            public void onClick(DialogInterface dialogInterface, int i) {
                Intent intent = new Intent(Settings.ACTION_WIRELESS_SETTINGS);
                startActivity(intent);
            }
        });
        builder.setNegativeButton(android.R.string.cancel, new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
            public void onClick(DialogInterface dialogInterface, int i) {
                finish();
            }
        });
        builder.create().show();
        return;
    }

    private void resolveIntent(Intent intent) {
        String action = intent.getAction();
        if (NfcAdapter.ACTION_TAG_DISCOVERED.equals(action)
                || NfcAdapter.ACTION_TECH_DISCOVERED.equals(action)
                || NfcAdapter.ACTION_NDEF_DISCOVERED.equals(action)) {
            Parcelable[] rawMsgs = intent.getParcelableArrayExtra(NfcAdapter.EXTRA_NDEF_MESSAGES);
            NdefMessage[] msgs;

            if (rawMsgs != null) {
                msgs = new NdefMessage[rawMsgs.length];
                for (int i = 0; i < rawMsgs.length; i++) {
                    msgs[i] = (NdefMessage) rawMsgs[i];
                }
            } else {
                // Unknown tag type
                byte[] empty = new byte[0];
                byte[] id = intent.getByteArrayExtra(NfcAdapter.EXTRA_ID);

                Parcelable tag = intent.getParcelableExtra(NfcAdapter.EXTRA_TAG);

                byte[] payload = dumpTagData(tag).getBytes();
                NdefRecord record = new NdefRecord(NdefRecord.TNF_UNKNOWN, empty, id, payload);
                NdefMessage msg = new NdefMessage(new NdefRecord[] { record });
                msgs = new NdefMessage[] { msg  } ;
            }
            // Setup the views
            buildTagViews(msgs);
        }

    }



    private String dumpTagData(Parcelable p) {
        StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
        Tag tag = (Tag) p;
        byte[] id = tag.getId();
        sb.append("Tag ID (hex): ").append(getHex(id)).append("\n");
        sb.append("Tag ID (dec): ").append(getDec(id)).append("\n");
        sb.append("ID (reversed): ").append(getReversed(id)).append("\n");

        String prefix = "android.nfc.tech.";
        sb.append("Technologies: ");
        for (String tech : tag.getTechList()) {
            sb.append(tech.substring(prefix.length()));
            sb.append(", ");
        }
        sb.delete(sb.length() - 2, sb.length());
        for (String tech : tag.getTechList()) {
            if (tech.equals(MifareClassic.class.getName())) {
                sb.append('\n');
                MifareClassic mifareTag = MifareClassic.get(tag);
                String type = "Unknown";
                switch (mifareTag.getType()) {
                    case MifareClassic.TYPE_CLASSIC:
                        type = "Classic";
                        break;
                    case MifareClassic.TYPE_PLUS:
                        type = "Plus";
                        break;
                    case MifareClassic.TYPE_PRO:
                        type = "Pro";
                        break;
                }
                sb.append("Mifare Classic type: ");
                sb.append(type);
                sb.append('\n');

                sb.append("Mifare size: ");
                sb.append(mifareTag.getSize() + " bytes");
                sb.append('\n');

                sb.append("Mifare sectors: ");
                sb.append(mifareTag.getSectorCount());
                sb.append('\n');

                sb.append("Mifare blocks: ");
                sb.append(mifareTag.getBlockCount());
            }

            if (tech.equals(MifareUltralight.class.getName())) {
                sb.append('\n');
                MifareUltralight mifareUlTag = MifareUltralight.get(tag);
                String type = "Unknown";
                switch (mifareUlTag.getType()) {
                    case MifareUltralight.TYPE_ULTRALIGHT:
                        type = "Ultralight";
                        break;
                    case MifareUltralight.TYPE_ULTRALIGHT_C:
                        type = "Ultralight C";
                        break;
                }
                sb.append("Mifare Ultralight type: ");
                sb.append(type);
            }
        }

        return sb.toString();
    }

    private String getHex(byte[] bytes) {
        StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
        for (int i = bytes.length - 1; i >= 0; --i) {
            int b = bytes[i] & 0xff;
            if (b < 0x10)
                sb.append('0');
            sb.append(Integer.toHexString(b));
            if (i > 0) {
                sb.append(" ");
            }
        }
        return sb.toString();
    }



    private long getDec(byte[] bytes) {
        long result = 0;
        long factor = 1;
        for (int i = 0; i < bytes.length; ++i) {
            long value = bytes[i] & 0xffl;
            result += value * factor;
            factor *= 256l;
        }
        return result;
    }

    private long getReversed(byte[] bytes) {
        long result = 0;
        long factor = 1;
        for (int i = bytes.length - 1; i >= 0; --i) {
            long value = bytes[i] & 0xffl;
            result += value * factor;
            factor *= 256l;
        }

        return result;

    }


    void buildTagViews(NdefMessage[] msgs) {

        if (msgs == null || msgs.length == 0) {
            return;
        }
        LayoutInflater inflater = LayoutInflater.from(this);
        LinearLayout content = mTagContent;

        // Parse the first message in the list
        // Build views for all of the sub records
        Date now = new Date();
        List<ParsedNdefRecord> records = NdefMessageParser.parse(msgs[0]);
        final int size = records.size();
        for (int i = 0; i < size; i++) {

            TextView timeView = new TextView(this);
            timeView.setText(TIME_FORMAT.format(now));
            content.addView(timeView, 0);
            ParsedNdefRecord record = records.get(i);

            content.addView(record.getView(this, inflater, content, i), 1 + i);
            content.addView(inflater.inflate(R.layout.tag_divider, content, false), 2 + i);


            // Getting the text from the TextView from tag_text.xml and presenting it as Toast
            TextView myTagView =  (TextView)findViewById(R.id.text);
            myTagId = myTagView.getText().toString();

            myCTagUrl = getString(R.string.ctag_url);
            mySTagUrl = getString(R.string.stag_url);


            if ((mCoffee9ImageView.getDrawable().getConstantState() == getResources().getDrawable(R.drawable.sbp_free_coffee).getConstantState()) && myCTagUrl.equals(myTagView.getText().toString())) {
                Toast toast = Toast.makeText(this, "You Redeemed Your Free\n" +
                        "Cup of Coffee, Thank You\n" +
                        "For Your Patronage!", Toast.LENGTH_LONG);
                TextView v = (TextView) toast.getView().findViewById(android.R.id.message);
                if (v != null) v.setGravity(Gravity.CENTER);
                toast.show();
                mCoffee1ImageView.setImageResource(R.drawable.sbp_coffee);
                mCoffee2ImageView.setImageResource(R.drawable.sbp_coffee);
                mCoffee3ImageView.setImageResource(R.drawable.sbp_coffee);
                mCoffee4ImageView.setImageResource(R.drawable.sbp_coffee);
                mCoffee5ImageView.setImageResource(R.drawable.sbp_coffee);
                mCoffee6ImageView.setImageResource(R.drawable.sbp_coffee);
                mCoffee7ImageView.setImageResource(R.drawable.sbp_coffee);
                mCoffee8ImageView.setImageResource(R.drawable.sbp_coffee);
                mCoffee9ImageView.setImageResource(R.drawable.sbp_coffee);

                return;

            } else if ((mCoffee1ImageView.getDrawable().getConstantState() != getResources().getDrawable(R.drawable.sbp_coffee_free).getConstantState()) && myCTagUrl.equals(myTagView.getText().toString())) {
                mCoffee1ImageView.setImageResource(R.drawable.sbp_coffee_free);

                //setCvisible();

                cflag = true;
                mCoffee1ImageView.setImageResource(R.drawable.sbp_coffee_free);
                SharedPreferences prefs = PreferenceManager.getDefaultSharedPreferences(this);
                prefs.edit().putBoolean("selected", true).commit();

                Toast toast = Toast.makeText(this, "Thanks!\n" +
                        "You Earned 1 Credit\n" +
                        "Towards a Free Coffee", Toast.LENGTH_LONG);
                TextView v = (TextView) toast.getView().findViewById(android.R.id.message);
                if (v != null) v.setGravity(Gravity.CENTER);
                toast.show();
                break;

            } else if ((mCoffee1ImageView.getDrawable().getConstantState() == getResources().getDrawable(R.drawable.sbp_coffee_free).getConstantState()) && myCTagUrl.equals(myTagView.getText().toString())
                    && ((mCoffee2ImageView.getDrawable().getConstantState() != getResources().getDrawable(R.drawable.sbp_coffee_free).getConstantState()))) {
                mCoffee2ImageView.setImageResource(R.drawable.sbp_coffee_free);
                Toast toast = Toast.makeText(this, "Thanks!\n" +
                        "You Have Earned 2 Credits\n" +
                        "Towards a Free Coffee", Toast.LENGTH_LONG);
                TextView v = (TextView) toast.getView().findViewById(android.R.id.message);
                if (v != null) v.setGravity(Gravity.CENTER);
                toast.show();
                break;

            } else if ((mCoffee2ImageView.getDrawable().getConstantState() == getResources().getDrawable(R.drawable.sbp_coffee_free).getConstantState()) && myCTagUrl.equals(myTagView.getText().toString())
                    && ((mCoffee3ImageView.getDrawable().getConstantState() != getResources().getDrawable(R.drawable.sbp_coffee_free).getConstantState()))) {
                mCoffee3ImageView.setImageResource(R.drawable.sbp_coffee_free);
                Toast toast = Toast.makeText(this, "Thanks!\n" +
                        "You Have Earned 3 Credits\n" +
                        "Towards a Free Coffee", Toast.LENGTH_LONG);
                TextView v = (TextView) toast.getView().findViewById(android.R.id.message);
                if (v != null) v.setGravity(Gravity.CENTER);
                toast.show();
                break;

            } else if ((mCoffee3ImageView.getDrawable().getConstantState() == getResources().getDrawable(R.drawable.sbp_coffee_free).getConstantState()) && myCTagUrl.equals(myTagView.getText().toString())
                    && ((mCoffee4ImageView.getDrawable().getConstantState() != getResources().getDrawable(R.drawable.sbp_coffee_free).getConstantState()))) {
                mCoffee4ImageView.setImageResource(R.drawable.sbp_coffee_free);
                Toast toast = Toast.makeText(this, "Thanks!\n" +
                        "You Have Earned 4 Credits\n" +
                        "Towards a Free Coffee", Toast.LENGTH_LONG);
                TextView v = (TextView) toast.getView().findViewById(android.R.id.message);
                if (v != null) v.setGravity(Gravity.CENTER);
                toast.show();
                break;

            } else if ((mCoffee4ImageView.getDrawable().getConstantState() == getResources().getDrawable(R.drawable.sbp_coffee_free).getConstantState()) && myCTagUrl.equals(myTagView.getText().toString())
                    && ((mCoffee5ImageView.getDrawable().getConstantState() != getResources().getDrawable(R.drawable.sbp_coffee_free).getConstantState()))) {
                mCoffee5ImageView.setImageResource(R.drawable.sbp_coffee_free);
                Toast toast = Toast.makeText(this, "Thanks!\n" +
                        "You're Over Half Way to\n" +
                        "a Free Cup of Coffee", Toast.LENGTH_LONG);
                TextView v = (TextView) toast.getView().findViewById(android.R.id.message);
                if (v != null) v.setGravity(Gravity.CENTER);
                toast.show();
                break;

            } else if ((mCoffee5ImageView.getDrawable().getConstantState() == getResources().getDrawable(R.drawable.sbp_coffee_free).getConstantState()) && myCTagUrl.equals(myTagView.getText().toString())
                    && ((mCoffee6ImageView.getDrawable().getConstantState() != getResources().getDrawable(R.drawable.sbp_coffee_free).getConstantState()))) {
                mCoffee6ImageView.setImageResource(R.drawable.sbp_coffee_free);
                Toast toast = Toast.makeText(this, "Thanks!\n" +
                        "You Have Earned 6 Credits\n" +
                        "Towards a Free Coffee", Toast.LENGTH_LONG);
                TextView v = (TextView) toast.getView().findViewById(android.R.id.message);
                if (v != null) v.setGravity(Gravity.CENTER);
                toast.show();
                break;

            } else if ((mCoffee6ImageView.getDrawable().getConstantState() == getResources().getDrawable(R.drawable.sbp_coffee_free).getConstantState()) && myCTagUrl.equals(myTagView.getText().toString())
                    && ((mCoffee7ImageView.getDrawable().getConstantState() != getResources().getDrawable(R.drawable.sbp_coffee_free).getConstantState()))) {
                mCoffee7ImageView.setImageResource(R.drawable.sbp_coffee_free);
                Toast toast = Toast.makeText(this, "Thanks!\n" +
                        "You Have Earned 7 Credits\n" +
                        "Towards a Free Coffee", Toast.LENGTH_LONG);
                TextView v = (TextView) toast.getView().findViewById(android.R.id.message);
                if (v != null) v.setGravity(Gravity.CENTER);
                toast.show();
                break;

            } else if ((mCoffee7ImageView.getDrawable().getConstantState() == getResources().getDrawable(R.drawable.sbp_coffee_free).getConstantState()) && myCTagUrl.equals(myTagView.getText().toString())
                    && ((mCoffee8ImageView.getDrawable().getConstantState() != getResources().getDrawable(R.drawable.sbp_coffee_free).getConstantState()))) {
                mCoffee8ImageView.setImageResource(R.drawable.sbp_coffee_free);
                Toast toast = Toast.makeText(this, "Thanks!\n" +
                        "You Have Earned 8 Credits\n" +
                        "Towards a Free Coffee", Toast.LENGTH_LONG);
                TextView v = (TextView) toast.getView().findViewById(android.R.id.message);
                if (v != null) v.setGravity(Gravity.CENTER);
                toast.show();
                break;

            } else if ((mCoffee8ImageView.getDrawable().getConstantState() == getResources().getDrawable(R.drawable.sbp_coffee_free).getConstantState()) && myCTagUrl.equals(myTagView.getText().toString())
                    && ((mCoffee9ImageView.getDrawable().getConstantState() != getResources().getDrawable(R.drawable.sbp_coffee_free).getConstantState()))) {
                mCoffee9ImageView.setImageResource(R.drawable.sbp_free_coffee);
                Toast toast = Toast.makeText(this, "CONGRATULATION!\n" +
                        "Your Next\n" +
                        "Cup of Coffee is on US!", Toast.LENGTH_LONG);
                TextView v = (TextView) toast.getView().findViewById(android.R.id.message);
                if (v != null) v.setGravity(Gravity.CENTER);
                toast.show();
                break;

            }

            if ((mSandwich9ImageView.getDrawable().getConstantState() == getResources().getDrawable(R.drawable.sbp_free_sandwich).getConstantState()) && mySTagUrl.equals(myTagView.getText().toString())) {
                Toast toast = Toast.makeText(this, "You Redeemed Your Free\n" +
                        "Sandwich, Thank You\n" +
                        "For Your Patronage!", Toast.LENGTH_LONG);
                TextView v = (TextView) toast.getView().findViewById(android.R.id.message);
                if (v != null) v.setGravity(Gravity.CENTER);
                toast.show();

                return;

            } else if ((mSandwich1ImageView.getDrawable().getConstantState() != getResources().getDrawable(R.drawable.sbp_sandwich_free).getConstantState()) && mySTagUrl.equals(myTagView.getText().toString())) {
                mSandwich1ImageView.setImageResource(R.drawable.sbp_sandwich_free);

                Toast toast = Toast.makeText(this, "Thanks!\n" +
                        "You Earned 1 Credit\n" +
                        "Towards a Free Sandwich", Toast.LENGTH_LONG);
                TextView v = (TextView) toast.getView().findViewById(android.R.id.message);
                if (v != null) v.setGravity(Gravity.CENTER);
                toast.show();
                break;

            } else if ((mSandwich1ImageView.getDrawable().getConstantState() == getResources().getDrawable(R.drawable.sbp_sandwich_free).getConstantState()) && mySTagUrl.equals(myTagView.getText().toString())
                    && ((mSandwich2ImageView.getDrawable().getConstantState() != getResources().getDrawable(R.drawable.sbp_sandwich_free).getConstantState()))) {
                mSandwich2ImageView.setImageResource(R.drawable.sbp_sandwich_free);
                Toast toast = Toast.makeText(this, "Thanks!\n" +
                        "You Have Earned 2 Credits\n" +
                        "Towards a Free Sandwich", Toast.LENGTH_LONG);
                TextView v = (TextView) toast.getView().findViewById(android.R.id.message);
                if (v != null) v.setGravity(Gravity.CENTER);
                toast.show();
                break;

            } else if ((mSandwich2ImageView.getDrawable().getConstantState() == getResources().getDrawable(R.drawable.sbp_sandwich_free).getConstantState()) && mySTagUrl.equals(myTagView.getText().toString())
                    && ((mSandwich3ImageView.getDrawable().getConstantState() != getResources().getDrawable(R.drawable.sbp_sandwich_free).getConstantState()))) {
                mSandwich3ImageView.setImageResource(R.drawable.sbp_sandwich_free);
                Toast toast = Toast.makeText(this, "Thanks!\n" +
                        "You Have Earned 3 Credits\n" +
                        "Towards a Free Sandwich", Toast.LENGTH_LONG);
                TextView v = (TextView) toast.getView().findViewById(android.R.id.message);
                if (v != null) v.setGravity(Gravity.CENTER);
                toast.show();
                break;

            } else if ((mSandwich3ImageView.getDrawable().getConstantState() == getResources().getDrawable(R.drawable.sbp_sandwich_free).getConstantState()) && mySTagUrl.equals(myTagView.getText().toString())
                    && ((mSandwich4ImageView.getDrawable().getConstantState() != getResources().getDrawable(R.drawable.sbp_sandwich_free).getConstantState()))) {
                mSandwich4ImageView.setImageResource(R.drawable.sbp_sandwich_free);
                Toast toast = Toast.makeText(this, "Thanks!\n" +
                        "You Have Earned 4 Credits\n" +
                        "Towards a Free Sandwich", Toast.LENGTH_LONG);
                TextView v = (TextView) toast.getView().findViewById(android.R.id.message);
                if (v != null) v.setGravity(Gravity.CENTER);
                toast.show();
                break;

            } else if ((mSandwich4ImageView.getDrawable().getConstantState() == getResources().getDrawable(R.drawable.sbp_sandwich_free).getConstantState()) && mySTagUrl.equals(myTagView.getText().toString())
                    && ((mSandwich5ImageView.getDrawable().getConstantState() != getResources().getDrawable(R.drawable.sbp_sandwich_free).getConstantState()))) {
                mSandwich5ImageView.setImageResource(R.drawable.sbp_sandwich_free);
                Toast toast = Toast.makeText(this, "Thanks!\n" +
                        "You're Over Half Way to\n" +
                        "Free Sandwich", Toast.LENGTH_LONG);
                TextView v = (TextView) toast.getView().findViewById(android.R.id.message);
                if (v != null) v.setGravity(Gravity.CENTER);
                toast.show();
                break;

            } else if ((mSandwich5ImageView.getDrawable().getConstantState() == getResources().getDrawable(R.drawable.sbp_sandwich_free).getConstantState()) && mySTagUrl.equals(myTagView.getText().toString())
                    && ((mSandwich6ImageView.getDrawable().getConstantState() != getResources().getDrawable(R.drawable.sbp_sandwich_free).getConstantState()))) {
                mSandwich6ImageView.setImageResource(R.drawable.sbp_sandwich_free);
                Toast toast = Toast.makeText(this, "Thanks!\n" +
                        "You Have Earned 6 Credits\n" +
                        "Towards a Free Sandwich", Toast.LENGTH_LONG);
                TextView v = (TextView) toast.getView().findViewById(android.R.id.message);
                if (v != null) v.setGravity(Gravity.CENTER);
                toast.show();
                break;

            } else if ((mSandwich6ImageView.getDrawable().getConstantState() == getResources().getDrawable(R.drawable.sbp_sandwich_free).getConstantState()) && mySTagUrl.equals(myTagView.getText().toString())
                    && ((mSandwich7ImageView.getDrawable().getConstantState() != getResources().getDrawable(R.drawable.sbp_sandwich_free).getConstantState()))) {
                mSandwich7ImageView.setImageResource(R.drawable.sbp_sandwich_free);
                Toast toast = Toast.makeText(this, "Thanks!\n" +
                        "You Have Earned 7 Credits\n" +
                        "Towards a Free Sandwich", Toast.LENGTH_LONG);
                TextView v = (TextView) toast.getView().findViewById(android.R.id.message);
                if (v != null) v.setGravity(Gravity.CENTER);
                toast.show();
                break;

            } else if ((mSandwich7ImageView.getDrawable().getConstantState() == getResources().getDrawable(R.drawable.sbp_sandwich_free).getConstantState()) && mySTagUrl.equals(myTagView.getText().toString())
                    && ((mSandwich8ImageView.getDrawable().getConstantState() != getResources().getDrawable(R.drawable.sbp_sandwich_free).getConstantState()))) {
                mSandwich8ImageView.setImageResource(R.drawable.sbp_sandwich_free);
                Toast toast = Toast.makeText(this, "Thanks!\n" +
                        "You Have Earned 8 Credits\n" +
                        "Towards a Free Sandwich", Toast.LENGTH_LONG);
                TextView v = (TextView) toast.getView().findViewById(android.R.id.message);
                if (v != null) v.setGravity(Gravity.CENTER);
                toast.show();
                break;

            } else if ((mSandwich8ImageView.getDrawable().getConstantState() == getResources().getDrawable(R.drawable.sbp_sandwich_free).getConstantState()) && mySTagUrl.equals(myTagView.getText().toString())
                    && ((mSandwich9ImageView.getDrawable().getConstantState() != getResources().getDrawable(R.drawable.sbp_sandwich_free).getConstantState()))) {
                mSandwich9ImageView.setImageResource(R.drawable.sbp_free_sandwich);
                Toast toast = Toast.makeText(this, "CONGRATULATION!\n" +
                        "Your Next\n" +
                        "Sandwich is on US!", Toast.LENGTH_LONG);
                TextView v = (TextView) toast.getView().findViewById(android.R.id.message);
                if (v != null) v.setGravity(Gravity.CENTER);
                toast.show();
                break;

            }
        }
    }


    private void setCvisible(){

        cflag = true;
        mCoffee1ImageView.setImageResource(R.drawable.sbp_coffee_free);
        SharedPreferences prefs = PreferenceManager.getDefaultSharedPreferences(this);
        prefs.edit().putBoolean("selected", true).commit();
    }

    private void setCInvisible(){

        cflag = false;
        mCoffee1ImageView.setImageResource(R.drawable.sbp_coffee);
        // save the flag
    }


    @Override
    public void onConfigurationChanged(final Configuration newConfig){
        super.onConfigurationChanged(newConfig);
        mDrawerToggle.onConfigurationChanged(newConfig);
    }
    @Override
    public void onBackPressed(){
        if(mDrawerLayout.isDrawerOpen(GravityCompat.START)){
            mDrawerLayout.closeDrawer(GravityCompat.START);
        }else{
            super.onBackPressed();
        }
    }
    @Override
    public void onSaveInstanceState(final Bundle outState){
        super.onSaveInstanceState(outState);
        outState.putInt(NAV_ITEM_ID, mNavItemId);
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
        // Handle action bar item clicks here. The action bar will
        // automatically handle clicks on the Home/Up button, so long
        // as you specify a parent activity in AndroidManifest.xml.
        final int id = item.getItemId();

        if(id== android.support.v7.appcompat.R.id.home){
            return mDrawerToggle.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
        }
        return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
    }

    /**
     * -Handles clicks on the navigation menu
     * @param menuItem
     * @return
     */
    @Override
    public boolean onNavigationItemSelected(final MenuItem menuItem) {
        //Update highlighted item in the navigation menu
        menuItem.setChecked(true);
        mNavItemId = menuItem.getItemId();

        // Time gap after closing the navigation to see animation
        mDrawerLayout.closeDrawer(GravityCompat.START);
        mDrawerActionHandler.postDelayed(new Runnable() {
            @Override
            public void run() {
                navigate(menuItem.getItemId());
            }
        }, DRAWER_CLOSE_DELAY_MS);
        return true;
    }



    @Override
    public void onNewIntent(Intent intent) {
        setIntent(intent);
        resolveIntent(intent);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

The best way is to store several entries in a database.
But sure you are also able to store your DrawableID(R.drawable.coffee..) in a SharedPreference.
I think that is not the best way but it works.

If you don't want to use a Database (or maybe you have only a few static entries) your solution could be:

```
SharedPreferences setting = getSharedPreferences("Images", 0);
String image    = setting.getString("Image"+(iterator), "empty");

// Set Image to ImageButton
if(!"empty".equals(image))
 imageButton.setImageResource(Integer.parseInt(image));
```

That is how you read your Data. 
Save your drawableID in the same way and your gone.

Comment: I updated the Above code..  I believe it is now saving the True or False value but now it is not updating the Images.  BTW, the images I am trying to update are in coffee_fragment.xml and not the main_activity.xml, but I am trying to do everything via the MainActivity.  Everything looks fine, and I don't get any errors, it's just not updating the images.  Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: While I still don't understand the +(iterator) I was able to adapt your answer and things are working great.  Thanks